# The dollar sign in the image src is not working in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am trying to display some images saved as SVG on the screen. For this purpose, I mapped them and gave them IDs based on their names.

This is my code:

```js
    const resumeBullets = [
        { label: "education", logoSrc: "education.svg" },
        { label: "Work History", logoSrc: "work-history.svg" },
        { label: "Skills", logoSrc: "programming-skills.svg" },
        { label: "Projects", logoSrc: "projects.svg" },
        { label: "Interests", logoSrc: "interests.svg" },
    ];

    const getBullets = () => {
        return resumeBullets.map((bullet, index) => (
            <div
                onClick={() => handleCarousal(index)}
                className={index === selectedBulletIndex ? "bullet selected-bullet" : "bullet"}
                key={index}
            >

                <img className='bullet-logo'
                    src= {require('../../assets/svg/${bullet.logoSrc}')}
                    alt='oops... no internet connection!'
                />
            </div>
        ))
    };
```

This is the error I get:

> ERROR in ./src/PortfolioContainer/Resume/Resume.js 345:13-58 Module
> not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../assets/svg/${bullet.logoSrc}'
> in 'D:\Job\portfolio\client\src\PortfolioContainer\Resume'

This is the look I expect:

[image: The look I expect]

This is the look I get:

[image: The look I get]

Where have I gone wrong? Is there any other dynamic way besides this one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using single-quotes `'` instead of backticks `` ` ``. If you don't know already, the backtick key should be in the upper left corner of your keyboard where the tilde key `~` is.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My problem is solved. But another problem has arisen.
```
src= {require(`../../assets/svg/${bullet.logoSrc}`.default)}
```
it says:
'''
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'undefined'
'''

Comment: I edited my last message.

Comment: never mind I find out what was my problem. tnq so much.